# free(): invalid pointer error on compilation after attempting to copy a string using a function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I am trying to copy a string using a function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *_strdup(char *str);

/**
 * main - Entry point of my program
 *
 * Return: Always 0.
 */
int main(void)
{
    char *s;

    s = _strdup("Copied String");
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed to allocate memory\n");
        return (1);
    }
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return (0);
}

/**
 * _strdup - This function returns a pointer to a new string
 * which is a duplicate of the string str
 *
 * @str: The string to be copied
 *
 * Return: On Success, this function returns a pointer to
 * the duplicated string. It returns NULL, if insufficent
 * memory was avaliable, and if str == NULL.
 */

char *_strdup(char *str)
{
        char *ch;

        if (str == NULL)
        {
                return (NULL);
        }
        ch = malloc(sizeof(*ch) * sizeof(*str));
        ch = str;
        return (ch);
}
```

As I run it, I get the following error:

```
Copied String
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It has copied the string, but as I try to free the memory space allocated it gives me an error. Why i it happening? How can I get around this?

Comment: `sizeof` isn't doing what you think here. `sizeof(*ch)` and `sizeof(*str)` are both 1, so you're only allocating 1 byte, no matter how long `str` is. You need to allocate `strlen(str) + 1`, then `strcpy(ch, str)`. `ch=str` doesn't duplicate the string, it makes both pointers point to the same string and creates a memory leak. [Here's `strdup` source](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strdup.c.html), but try to think thru it first.

Comment: Using identifiers starting with `_` is unwise. I really wonder where that fashion is coming from after all "reserved" never means "reserved for you". If it was reserved for you, there would be a waiter taking the "reserved" label away when/before you sit down at the table.

Answer (score 4):

Here you malloc something which you could legally use `free()` on.
`ch = malloc(sizeof(*ch) * sizeof(*str));`.
Though I doubt the calculation of the size there....

Here, right in the next line, you throw that away and replace it by something which you can not legally use `free()` on.

`ch = str;`

And then you return it towards where it you attempt to use `free()` on it.

`return (ch);`

In total you basically attempt

`free("Copied String");`